# Huawei K4203i data card is not connecting to Internet in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, internet, usb-modem

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and I landed up in very miserable situation. I've purchased new Huawei data card last week and tried all  possible ways to connect to internet, outlined in this forum, but no success. Data card is been detected by `lsusb` command. Output as below:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

Output of usb-devices as below:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=1506 Rev=01.02
S:  Manufacturer=HUAWEI
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
C:  #Ifs= 6 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=03 Prot=01 Driver=option
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=03 Prot=16 Driver=option
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=03 Prot=03 Driver=option
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=03 Prot=02 Driver=option
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

Despite all efforts, it seems I missed something which is not allowing me to connect to internet (either way - Network Manager or wvdial). However, it is working absolutely fine on Fedora 21 box. I'd be so happy if somebody would get me out of this situation. :(

Looking forward to your valuable suggestion at your earliest convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch modem to modem+card reader mode.

You can do it by running in terminal

```
echo -e 'AT^SETPORT="A1,A2;10,12,13,A2"\r' | sudo tee  /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Then re-plug the modem, and wait for 20-30 seconds.

Mobile connection option should appear in Network Manager menu. You will be able to setup connection.

**Note:** After this setting "Mobile Partner" in Windows will not work in Windows. If you need to use the modem in Windows, then setup a telephone connection there or reset the modem to factory settings by

```
echo -e 'AT^SETPORT="A1,A2;12,16,A1,A2"\r' | sudo tee /dev/ttyUSB0
```

It is also possible to use this modem in "Network Card" mode in Ubuntu, but you will need to setup connections in CLI.

Comment: I tried to connect as suggested, but no luck...however, I'm able to create mobile broadband connection via Network Manager menu.

Comment: So after you created the connection, why not just click the connection? It may not work if you changed `/etc/network/interfaces` or something else.

Comment: After creating the new connection I'm trying since then, but all in vain :( . Still unable to establish a connection. Just to confirm, I haven't made any changes to `/etc/network/interfaces`, I'm still novice to Linux...

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` to your question.

Comment: `cat /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`

Comment: I can't debug it, because I do not have this modem now. But it looks that it is recognized as a modem now by Network Manager. I have a same modem, but it is at another place. It works after that command.

Comment: Many thanks anyway @Pilot6.  Your time and efforts are very much appreciated...